# Create panel for HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQUery and trying to create a panel for my HTML page.
The panel contains mutiple divs.

My JavaScript function is:

```
function createQuestionPanel() {
    var topDiv = $('<div>top div</div>');
    var questionDiv = $('<div>bottom div</div>');
    topDiv.after(questionDiv);
    return topDiv;
}
```

I call this function and append it to another JQuery representation of a HTML element.  The problem is it only displays the topdiv. I want it to display both the bottom and top div.  Do I need to wrap all the divs in my createQuestionPanel() method or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just add another `div` layer:

```
function createQuestionPanel() {
    var div = $('<div>');
    $('<div>top div</div>').appendTo(div);
    $('<div>bottom div</div>').appendTo(div);
    return div;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/d7MtM/

Or you can return an array of jQuery objects:

```
function createQuestionPanel() {
    var topDiv = $('<div>top div</div>');
    var questionDiv = $('<div>bottom div</div>');
    return [topDiv, questionDiv];
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/RhCpe/

Comment: are you sure this works?  You don't close the div.  It does not work for me.

Comment: @dublintech theres a lot of mistakes..  `$.ready(` <-- needs fixing ... and you didn't use Neal's examples in your fiddle.. You didn't select `jQuery` from the menu.. http://jsfiddle.net/QNLH3/

Answer (score 1):

You can just add them together

```
function createQuestionPanel() {
    var div = $('<div>top div</div><div>bottom div</div>');
    return div;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward, create two elements with jQuery, give them different text and `add()` them together, returned in the same line as it's still readable in my opinion :

```
function createQuestionPanel() {
  return $('<div />', {text: 'top div'}).add($('<div />', {text: 'bottom div'}));
}
```

Comment: @Neal - I do that all the time, push()'ing elements to an array in a loop etc. But I've never really found any documentation to support it for jQuery, only thing I've seen is using an emtpy $() and add()'ing to it, but an array has always worked just fine for me, so +1.